# What happens if part of the Kudu deployment to Azure fails?

Tags: .net, azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, kudu

We use a custom deploy.cmd script to do Kudu deployments to Azure on checkin to git. There are 4 projects/solutions being deployed in this file. I modified the existing default script so thst for each project we get Nuget, do msbuild, then do kudusync. If some projects build and sync successfully but others don't then an error is generated and the deploy is failed. What state is the website in at this point? Will it have some fixes but not others or is everything reverted? If not the latter, then is it possible to do the whole thing as an all or nothing approach?

Much Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do a true atomic deployment. So your build script will do whatever it does, and that's the state you'll be in.

However, you can choose to write your script in a way that avoids issues by doing all the builds first, and not doing kudusync until the very end. As long as you don't run kudusync, your wwwroot is not affected (unless you go out of your way to modify it outside of kudusync).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I will do then.